# Google Closure Compiler Externs and Function Arguments

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Consider a typical function extern:

```
var func = function(arg1, arg2) {};
```

**Question:** When declaring function externs like this, does the Google Closure Compiler care if we get the correct number of arguments? For example, we could replace the above with the following:

```
var func = function() {};
```

As an aside, I tried making my externs without any arguments, and the GCC didn't seem to care; however, I'm just making sure I'm not going to run into an unforseen problem going about things this way.

Answer (score 1):

An extern function  without any annotation is assumed to take a variable number of arguments of any type and can return any type. As soon as a single annotation is added, the behavior changes and the compiler will warn about the number and type of arguments.

```
/** @return {undefined} */
var func = function()  {} ;
```

The compiler team will only accept externs that are completely typed because of this.

Comment: Really we should drop that behavior.  If you want an untype checked function you can declare:

/** @type {!Function} */ var func;